# Addition results in JavaScript giving error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

```
$(document).on('pageshow','#temperatureContents',function(){
    $(document).off('click','#convertbtnTemp').on('click','#convertbtnTemp',function(){
        textFieldValue = $('#numberField').val();
    });
});

if(selectFrom == "celcius" && selectTo == "kelvin"){ 
    celToKel(selectFrom,selectTo,textFieldValue);
}

function celToKel(selectFrom,selectTo,textFieldValue){  
    var value = Number(textFieldValue).toFixed(1);
    var result = (value + 273.15);
    displayResult(selectFrom,selectTo,result);
}

function displayResult(selectFrom,selectTo,result){
    $('#resultDiv').show();
    $('#resultDisplay').empty().append("the  Result  of " +  selectFrom + "   to    " + selectTo + "   is:   " +   result);
}
```

the problem is with these two lines it giving me **1 + 273.15 = 1.0273.15**   but i want to add 1 in 273.15   how can i get this?

```
 var value = Number(textFieldValue).toFixed(1);
 var result = (value + 273.15);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of [`Number.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) is a string. So in your code the `+` operator will perform a string concatenation and you get your result `"1.0273.15"`.

What you want may be more along these lines. Use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert your input value to a number, then do the calculations and in the end apply `toFixed()` to have the correct amount of decimals.

```
// ...
var value = parseInt(textFieldValue, 10 );
var result = (value + 273.15).toFixed(1);
displayResult(selectFrom,selectTo,result);
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `value` is being treated like a string. Probably because of the `.toFixed(1)`modification. However, you can force it to bet treated as a number again by doing one of the following

1. `result= (value*1) + 273.15`
2. `result= parseInt(value) + 273.15`